# Parse JSON array without keys in Retrofit 2

Tags: json, parsing, nested, retrofit2

I'm trying to parse a nested json array without any key like this with Retrofit on Android but it seems hard to process now:

```
[
  [
    [
      "demo description",
      "demo",
      null,
      null,
      1
    ]
  ],
  null,
  "en"
]
```

I've tried with List but got error message like: error: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

I'm using Retrofit 2.

Many thanks

Comment: OK found it, just change the converterFactory of Retrofit from GsonConverterFactory to ScalarsConverterFactory.create


new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                        .addCallAdapterFactory(ErrorHandlerFactory.create())
                        .baseUrl(Config.BASE_END_POINT)
                        .client(httpClient.build())
                        .build();

Comment: got any solution?